# Windows Service in Java

Tags: java, windows-services

I am writing application in java that supports windows service, I use this URL: http://benjsicam.me/blog/running-a-java-application-as-a-windows-service-part-1-tutorial/
But when I run application, I cannot show any service in manage-> windows services, is the java support windows service when system is starting the service start automatically? If your answer is yes, please describe about it.

Best Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider Apache Commons Daemon.

http://commons.apache.org/daemon/procrun.html

It allows to run your java application as a windows service which is manageable via service control panel.

**UPDATE:**

as you have downloaded the package, there is an exe file: **prunsrv.exe**

it is a key file to install/uninstall your java app as a Windows service.

below, there's a command to install new service "MyServiceName", located in `MyCustomServiceJavaApp.jar` with the main class: `com.mycustomservice.Application`

```
prunsrv //IS//MyServiceName --DisplayName="My Custom Service" --Jvm=auto --Classpath=MyCustomServiceJavaApp.jar --StartMode=jvm --StartClass=com.mycustomservice.Application --Startup=Auto
```

This service will start automatically upon Windows startup.

To manage this service you can use Windows Services Control Panel.

To uninstall the service, execute the command:

```
prunsrv //DS//MyServiceName
```

Please note that `prunsrv.exe` and `MyCustomServiceJavaApp.jar` files for this example are located in the same folder.

More information about the Apache Commons Daemon you can find by the link I provided above.

Comment: Thank you, can you more explain about this?

Comment: @user3693568 I have updated my answer. Please check it.

Comment: Thank you alot, all of things work well, but i have question, does it use license?

Comment: Apache Commons has been distributed with Apache License: http://www.apache.org/licenses/   It is permissive license and commercial use is permitted. Also check this link too: http://choosealicense.com/licenses/apache/